# JWindow alway on top not getting focus events

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jwindow

I have a jwindow(set to be always on top) that you can click to get a pop menu. If the user right clicks the window it shows the pop menu but then if the user clicks any other window(such as firefox) pop menu does not disappear.

I tried to fix it by adding FocusListener on the jwindow, i implemented FocusListener and override

```
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
    System.out.println("gain" );
    }

    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
    System.out.println("lost" );
    }
```

but there event never get called. i also tried the following,

```
    addWindowFocusListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
            System.out.println("gain 2" );
        }
        });
```

this event also not called.

All this jwindows has is a single JLabel with a picture on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From memory JWindow's do not receive focus/window events.

Comment: yep thats the case switched to JFrame set it to undecorated solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are suppose to call `setFocusableWindowState(true)` on a `JWindow` to allow it to be focusable.  But that "still" is not enough.  The `JWindow` must also have focusable Components and I'm still not able to get it to work.
Using `JFrame setUndecorated()` seems the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

To be focusable, a `JWindow` needs to be created with a parent `Frame`, like `new JWindow(parentFrame)`.  Do that and I think you should find it will automatically get the focus when you set it to visible.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are trying to do. If you are trying to hide the popup manually then you should probably use a WindowListener and handle the windowDeactivated event.

Comment: i don't want to deactivate popup manually i am doing it because swing doesn't do it. just as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to display a popup menu, you should be using JPopupMenu, not implementing it yourself.